# 3 boxes need to be moved to the left

Tags: html, css

I have a problem! I made 3 boxes which can be seen when you click on a button. The problem is that the boxes are moved to the right. They need to be moved to the left a little bit. I tried to fix it with a big div that will be set to `left:5%;` but it didnt help... If you dont know what I want to say, here's the picture- [The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRCT6.jpg). Please change my code with yours and thank you! :D

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    background-size: auto 120%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right !important;
}
  
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0074D9;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 color: white !important;
 font-family:arial;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #0047b3 !important;
}

.active {
    background-color:#0047b3;
}

a:link{
 color:#0074D9;
}
a:visited{
 color:#0074D9;
}
a:hover{
 color:#001f3f;
}
a:active{
 color:#001f3f;
}

hr{
 height:3px;
 background-color:#0080ff;
 border:0px;
 transform: translateY(-95%);
 margin: 35px -9999rem;
    padding: 0.10rem 9999rem;
}
button{
 background-color:#0074D9;
 border-radius:10px;
 font-family:arial;
 border-color:transparent;
 padding:9px;
 font-size:18;
 width:150px;
 color: white;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 27px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-right: 80px;
}
button:visited{
 color:#0074D9;
}
button:hover{
 background-color:#0047b3;
}
button:active{
 color:#0047b3;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#left {
 left:5% !important;
 bottom:50% !important;
 float:left;
 display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    margin: 56px;
 vertical-align:-200%;
 font-family:arial !important;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:white;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


#middle {
 left: 38%;
 bottom:50%;
 display:block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
 position: absolute !important;;
 top:30% !important;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 30px;
 margin-left:-20px !important;
 margin-right:-20px !important;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
 
#right {
 float:right;
 right: 15% !important;
 bottom:50%;
 display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding:30px;
    margin: 56px 25px -20px !important;
 vertical-align:-200%;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#allbox{
 left:5% !important;
 bottom:50% !important;
 vertical-align:-200% !important;
}

#left, #middle, #right{
 height: 130px
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Moj web</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body background="http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg">

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clicky").click(function(){
        $("#welcomeDiv").fadeToggle();
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clicky2").click(function(){
        $("#welcomeDiver").fadeToggle();
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clicky1").click(function(){
        $("#welcomeDiverer").fadeToggle();
    });
});
</script>

    <center>
        <div>
            <button id="clicky" style="margin-right: 75px">Press me!</button>
            <button id="clicky1" style="margin-right: 75px">Press me!</button>
            <button id="clicky2" style="margin-right: 75px">Press me!</button>
        </div>
    </center>
    <br>
    <br>

  <div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;">
   <div id="left">
    <p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br> Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br> Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="welcomeDiver" style="display:none;">
   <div id="right">
    <p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br> Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br> Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="welcomeDiverer" style="display:none;">
   <div id="middle">
    <p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br> Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br> Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 
    <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need all the boxes to move left or only the leftmost??

Comment: I need them to be aligned more to the left cuz they are aligned too much to the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are aligned too much to the right is because you have `margin-right` as `25px` to the right div with `margin: 56px 25px -20px !important;` Now because the left div is a `56px left-margin` from the screen where as right div is at `25px right-margin` from thr screen which is less from left div and thus it is looking more right aligned to you. Changing to `margin:56px` to right div will make it aligned equal from both ends

```css
   
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    background-size: auto 120%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right !important;
}
  
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0074D9;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 color: white !important;
 font-family:arial;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #0047b3 !important;
}

.active {
    background-color:#0047b3;
}

a:link{
 color:#0074D9;
}
a:visited{
 color:#0074D9;
}
a:hover{
 color:#001f3f;
}
a:active{
 color:#001f3f;
}

hr{
 height:3px;
 background-color:#0080ff;
 border:0px;
 transform: translateY(-95%);
 margin: 35px -9999rem;
    padding: 0.10rem 9999rem;
}
button{
 background-color:#0074D9;
 border-radius:10px;
 font-family:arial;
 border-color:transparent;
 padding:9px;
 font-size:18;
 width:150px;
 color: white;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 27px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-right: 80px;
}
button:visited{
 color:#0074D9;
}
button:hover{
 background-color:#0047b3;
}
button:active{
 color:#0047b3;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#left {
 left:5% !important;
 bottom:50% !important;
 float:left;
 display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    margin: 56px;
 vertical-align:-200%;
 font-family:arial !important;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:white;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


#middle {
 left: 38%;
 bottom:50%;
 display:block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
 position: absolute !important;;
 top:30% !important;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 30px;
 margin-left:-20px !important;
 margin-right:-20px !important;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
 
#right {
 float:right;
 right: 15% !important;
 bottom:50%;
 display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding:30px;
    margin: 56px; //new margin
 vertical-align:-200%;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#allbox{
 left:5% !important;
 bottom:50% !important;
 vertical-align:-200% !important;
}

#left, #middle, #right{
 height: 130px;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Moj web</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body background="http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg">

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clicky").click(function(){
        $("#welcomeDiv").fadeToggle();
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clicky2").click(function(){
        $("#welcomeDiver").fadeToggle();
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clicky1").click(function(){
        $("#welcomeDiverer").fadeToggle();
    });
});
</script>

    <center>
        <div>
            <button id="clicky" style="margin-right: 75px">Press me!</button>
            <button id="clicky1" style="margin-right: 75px">Press me!</button>
            <button id="clicky2" style="margin-right: 75px">Press me!</button>
        </div>
    </center>
    <br>
    <br>

  <div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;">
   <div id="left">
    <p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br> Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br> Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="welcomeDiver" style="display:none;">
   <div id="right">
    <p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br> Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br> Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="welcomeDiverer" style="display:none;">
   <div id="middle">
    <p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br> Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br> Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 
    <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have given `margin : 56px;` to `#left {}` try changing it accordingly